# How to extract specific dependencies in multiple vendor files using Vue CLI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

Currently when building a single page Vue CLI app, a single vendors chunk will be built containing all dependencies.  I am looking for a way to extract specific dependencies into a separate vendor file, so you would then have two.  So after build it would look something like:

```
  dist/js/chunk-vendors.12344566.js          479.34 KiB                                                               
  dist/js/chunk-vendors-jquery.222e1476.js   138.17 KiB
```

Laravel mix appears to provide [similar functionality](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/extract).  I am wondering how this is possible in a Vue CLI app.

Answer (score 2):

This is done through Webpack's [`splitChunks.cacheGroups`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunkscachegroups) config, which can be set in the [`configureWebpack`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack) option of [`vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js). In the `cacheGroups` object, define "groups" to split out specific dependencies:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
        minSize: 0,
        cacheGroups: {
          vuetify: {
            // regex to compare against build resource by path name (e.g., `/node_modules/vuetify`)
            test: /vuetify/,

            // basename of output file
            name: 'chunk-vendors-vuetify'
          }
        },
      },
    },
  }
}
```